# Pass parameters to server side with asyncfileupload (ajaxcontroltoolkit)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use ASP.NET and i need an easy way to upload a file asynchronously. So I tried to use asyncfileupload (Ajax control toolkit) but I also need to pass parameters to the server side. How can I do that ? thanks.

Here is my code :

on client side :

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
 <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuMedia" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern" OnUploadedComplete="afuMedia_UploadedComplete" />
```

on server side :

```
  protected void afuMedia_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
  {
      //int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
      string mediaPath = ConfigurationParameters.MediaPath;
      string filePath = CurrentBrand.BrandCode + "\\" + CurrentCulture.CultureCode + "\\" + "highlights-" + id;
      string physicalPath = Path.Combine(MapPath("~/" + mediaPath), filePath);

      afuMedia.SaveAs(physicalPath);
  }
```

Comment: read this http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx   read and let me know if you still need help

Comment: @skhurams, I did and there's no way to pass parameters to server side.

Comment: What kind of parameters explain?

Comment: an id to identify the table row

Comment: let me know if this works i have answered this

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanel ???

Comment: I don't use an update panel. I use a ToolkitScriptManager.

Comment: use ToolkitScriptManager  or scriptmanager doesnt matter

Comment: Debug your code and let me know what is filename you getting

Comment: On server side I get the proper file name, but the file is associated with a database entry identified by an 'id'. And that's this id I need.

Comment: Where from this id value comes? Is it already in url?

Comment: @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy, it is known after the page load, when the user choose to upload a file associated with a database entry (in a table row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add client handler for upload start via the `OnClientUploadStarted` property and use it as below:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuMedia" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern"
    OnUploadedComplete="afuMedia_UploadedComplete" 
    OnClientUploadStarted="afuMedia_OnClientUploadStarted" />

function afuMedia_OnClientUploadStarted(sender, args){
    var id = 123;
    var url = sender.get_postBackUrl();
    url += url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";
    url += ("id=" + id.toString());
    sender.set_postBackUrl(url);
}
```

With this code all that you need to do on you own it's to provide correct id value;

Comment: The query string data set using the above code does not appear to be available on the server side UploadComplete event.  I'm using the June 2013 release.

Comment: Great, it works but only problem is that when there is full page post back anything appended in the URL is shown in the address bar.